# Getting JSON content in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a wishlist page on my website and everything works but I'd like to optimize the code by getting content from a remote JSON file instead of inline in my script.js file, which I'm using now.

The JSON file is located in `./js/content.json` and needs to be obtained by script.js so it can send it to the HTML with handlebars.

### HTML (template):

```
<script id="wishlist-item" type="text/template">
    <li><i class="{{icon}}"></i> <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{title}} 
    <span class="valuta">&euro;{{price}}</span></a></li>
</script>
```

### Example wishlist item in items.json:

```
"items": [
        {
            "title": "A title",
            "icon": "fa fa-music",
            "location": "(Web)",
            "url": "http://linktowebsite.be",
            "price": 25.15
        },
        etc
```

### Script.js:

```
(function(){
  function init(){

        var wishText = $('#wishlist-item').text(); //get the template from html
        var template = Handlebars.compile(wishText); //compile template to variable

        for(var i = 0; i <= wishlist.items.length-1; i++){ //loop data which is inline in var wishlist at the moment
            var wishlistItem = template(wishlist.items[i]); //set each item in the data as a template
            $('.wishlist').append(wishlistItem); //append to a div with class wishlist
        }
    }

  init();

})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, use `$.getJSON()`:

```
function init(){
    var wishText = $('#wishlist-item').text(); //get the template from html
    var template = Handlebars.compile(wishText); //compile template to variable

    $.getJSON("js/content.json", function(data) {
          for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){ //loop data which is inline in var wishlist at the moment
             var wishlistItem = template(data.items[i]); //set each item in the data as a template
              $('.wishlist').append(wishlistItem); //append to a div with class wishlist
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before and the console doesn't give any errors but no data is loaded though. Maybe something wrong in the JSON file?
http://paste.ofcode.org/6emeBCHeVx2tbekBGg9LRy i pasted the full content here

Comment: yeah, that's not valid json. jsonlint.org

Comment: damn seems like I forget to open and close with {} and got a straying ,
. Thanks everyone!